# Docker and SSH for development with phpStorm

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to setup a small development environment using Docker. phpStorm team is working hard on get Docker integrated for remote interpreter and therefore for debugging but sadly is not working yet (see [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33437)). The only way I have to add such capabilities for debugging is by creating and enabling an SSH access to the container which works like a charm.

Now, I have read a lot about this and some people like the one on [this post](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/) says is not recommended. I have read others which says to have a dedicated SSH Docker container which I don't get how to fit on this environment.

I am already creating a user `docker-user` (check repo [here](https://github.com/reypm/php55-dev)) for certain tasks like run `composer` without root permissions. That could be used for this SSH stuff easily by adding a default password to it.

How would you handle this under such circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too have implemented the ssh server workaround when using jetbrains IDEs.

Usually what I do is add a public ssh key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the SSH user in the target container/system, and enable passwordless sudo.

One solution that I've thought of, but not yet had the time to implement, would be to make some sort of SSH service that would be a gateway to a `docker exec` command. That would potentially allow at least some functionality without having to modify your images in any way for this dev requirement.

Comment: I am not following you on this "make some sort of SSH service that would be a gateway to a docker exec command" I am not sure what are you trying to show me

Comment: basically, the idea is to create an ssh service that instead of dropping you into a normal shell, would drop you into a `docker exec` session instead. It can probably be made to work with some fancy ssh daemon configuration-- it's just a high level concept that I haven't actually tried yet. I thought it might be worth mentioning since you are trying to solve the same thing I was when I thought of it, but it certainly isn't the only possible way forward.

Comment: That's advanced stuff for me. I am learning Docker on the path. For now I will try to make SSH available on the container although I will never try to SSH into the container, for that we have `docker exec` and `docker attach` this SSH access is only for setup phpStorm PHP interpreter and possibly utilities, what do you think?